# In angularjs, Enable the button after the user uploads the image, otherwise the button should be disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to disable the button when user has not uploaded anything. After user uploads the image, I want to enable the button.

I am trying to use `ng-disabled`, but I am not sure how to set the `file-uploaded` to true after user uploads the image.

```
<form action="/api/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="myFile" ng-model="model.file-uploaded" type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control"/>
        <input name="width" value="{{model.widget.width}}" style="display: none"/>
        <input name="widgetId" value="{{model.widget._id}}" style="display: none"/>
        <input name="pageId" value="{{model.pageId}}" style="display: none"/>
        <input name="websiteId" value="{{model.websiteId}}" style="display: none"/>
        <input name="userId" value="{{model.userId}}" style="display: none"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" ng-disabled="model.file-uploaded">Upload Image</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: with form as shown you would be reloading page using conventional form submit and whatever `/api/upload` redirects to or outputs as new page.  Seems to be a lot missing here if you plan to upload using javascript

Comment: Do you really mean the image has to be "uploaded", or simply selected using the `input[type="file"]` element? In case of actually uploading, you should post the code that performs the upload.

Answer (score 0):

In ng-disable directive mention the method name GetFileSize() and inside the method return true or false based on the validation. Use jquery code to access the elements from the dom inside GerFileSize() method.